# How to convert a string with timezone to unix timestamp python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a datetime string I get from a database and I want to convert it to unix timestamp.

I am not sure what is the way to do it.

```
db_timestamp = '2020-08-05 12:48:50+02:00'
f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
timestamp = datetime.strptime(db_timestamp , f)
```

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

Another way I tried was as following

```
python_timestamp = datetime.isoformat(db_timestamp)
test_timestamp = datetime.strptime(python_timestamp , f)
```

Then I get the following error

```
ValueError: time data '2020-08-05T12:48:50+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
```

How to fix this error?
What should be the correct string format for db_timestamp?

Comment: in your example, `db_timestamp` has a date/time string in another format as you show in the `ValueError` - which one is it actually? Both formats are [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compatible, so `fromisoformat` will work (see my answer).

Comment: You should get different errors (or in a different order) than you have shown. I get the last error for the first code sample.

Comment: Which Python 3.x version are you using? (what is x?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you run Python 3.7 or higher, what you want is `fromisoformat` to parse the string and `timestamp()` to get seconds since the epoch UNIX time (POSIX).

```
from datetime import datetime
db_timestamp = '2020-08-05 12:48:50+02:00'
# to datetime object:
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(db_timestamp)
# to UNIX time:
ts = dt.timestamp()
print(repr(dt), ts)
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 12, 48, 50, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200))) 1596624530.0
```

Comment: @jmf: glad I could help. one more thing, be aware that if your input string does not contain a UTC offset, Python will assume that it is *local time* (your OS setting) - the resulting UNIX timestamp then considers the local time's UTC offset.